# Write/Read a series of different serialized objects to/from a file

Tags: java, image, file, serialization, read-write

I have a collection of objects:

```
Map<BufferedImage, Map<ImageTransform, Set<Point>>> map
```

I want to write those to a file, and then be able to read them back in the same struct.

---

I can't just write the collection as it is, because BufferedImage doesn't implement the `Serializable` (nor the `Externalizable`) interface. So I need to use the methods from the `ImageIO` class to write the image.

`ImageTransform` is a custom object that implements `Serializable`. So, I believe the *value* part of my map collection, should be writeable as it is.

---

Here is what I do to **write** to the file:

```
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    for (BufferedImage image : map.keySet()) {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", out);  // write the image to the stream
        out.writeObject(map.get(image));   // write the 'value' part of the map
    }
```

Here is what I do to **read** back from the file:

```
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    while(true) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
            Map<ImageTransform, Set<Point>> value = 
                (Map<ImageTransform, Set<Point>>) in.readObject(); // marker
            map.put(image, value);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. I get a `java.io.OptionalDataException` at *marker*.

```
java.io.OptionalDataException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1300)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
```

---

My question is, firstly, is the writing concept correct ? is `ImageIO#write` good for this case, or should I think about using/storing the `BufferedImage#getRgb` `int[]` array ? is the array more compact (as in, takes up less space in the file) ?
Secondly, how should I be reading the object back from the file ? How do I know when the EOF is reached ? Why doesn't the above work ?

I hope the info provided is enough, if you need more info on something, please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working as ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream write/expect a certain file format that is violated when you write an image out of order. To use ObjectStreams successfully you will need to observe the contract that is specifed by ObjectStreams.

To do this you will need to create a holding class, and use this class as the key to your map instead of BufferedImages. This holding class should implement Serializable and a three methods (not in any actual interface) that mark the Class as needing special handling during reading and writing. The method signatures must be exactly as specified or serialization won't work.

For more information have a look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) on ObjectOutputStream.

```
public class ImageHolder implements Serializable {

    BufferedImage image;

    public ImageHolder(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) 
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        image = ImageIO.read(stream);
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) 
            throws IOException {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", stream);
    }

    private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
        // leave image as null
    }
```

And then serialsation should be as simple as `outputStream.writeObject(map)`. Though you will need to check that the implementing class of ImageTransform is serialisable too.

Comment: yep, I had this in mind and I'm keen on giving this a good look. I think it's clean enough to be a really good solution, if I make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to 'cheat' and only have a single object to serialize is to add the group of objects to an expandable, serializable list.  Then serialize the list.

BTW - I would tend to use `XMLEncoder` over serialized Objects because they can be restored in later JVMs.  There is no such guarantee for serialized Objects.

---

> @Ivan c00kiemon5ter V Kanak:  *"I'm trying to keep the file as small in size as possible,..*

That is often wasted effort, given disk space is so cheap.

> *.. so I guess Serialization is better for that. *

Don't guess.  Measure.

> *..I'll try using a List and see how that goes. ..*

Cool.  Note that if using the `XMLEncoder`, I'd recommend Zipping it in most cases.  That would reduce the file size of the cruft of XML.  This situation is different in storing images.

Image formats typically incorporate compression of a type that is not conducive to being further compressed by Zip.  That can be side-stepped by storing the XML compressed, and the images as 'raw' in separate entries in the Zip.  OTOH I think you'll find the amount of bytes saved by compressing the XML alone is not worth the effort - given the final file size of the image entries.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the file as small in size as possible, so I guess Serialization is better for that. I'll try using a List and see how that goes. Thanks

Comment: _Don't guess. Measure._ I was expecting that :) I will measure. I'd like to minimize space, because I'm working on a compression system. So, I should be taking care about what gets stored, and what not. As I said, I'll look into `XMLEncoder`, make some tests and learn a couple of new things along the way.

Comment: 'OOS does not play well with multiple Objects' Eh? Don't tell RMI. Of course it does. You can write as many objects as you like to an ObjectOutputStream, and read them back until you get EOFException.